# How to open camera with default camera function in android app?

Tags: android, camera

i want to open camera in my android app and want to use paranomic effect of default mobile camera in my app how can we do this in android.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in the first place, incl. elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). Majority of newbies' questions are not unique and has already been answered multiple times.

Comment: Marcin Orlowski  i have already searched before posting

Answer (score 1):

> i want to open camera in my android app

Use one of the following `Intent` actions, all defined on `MediaStore`:

- `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`
- `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE`
- `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`
- `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`
- `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE`
- `INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA`

> and want to use paranomic effect of default mobile camera

There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread over thousands of device models. There are hundreds of different pre-installed camera apps, and hundreds more that the user can install from the Play Store or other distribution channels. Your `Intent` might open any of them.

None have to offer any sort of "paranomic effect".

Comment: did you know how to get the clicked image path when open camera using INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE

Comment: @saurabhdixit: You don't. That is simply to open the camera. If you want to get a picture back, use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE`. Please note that there is no requirement for the user's camera app to behave the same for all `Intent` actions. If you are expecting certain camera functionality, **write that functionality yourself**.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "filename.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Comment: i am not asking for taking picture using camera what i am asking is open camera with all functionality which default camera have.