# Android open up apps that use the camera permission?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I want to send the user away from my app to their camera app. The intention is that the user will be directed to open a camera app that allows for the scanning of QR codes.

What **will** work:

- Attempt to open the default camera (not sure this is possible considering all the variables across Android)
- A dialog chooser that shows apps that use the camera permission
- A chooser that show camera apps as an option

What **won't** work:

- MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

---

So far from what I have seen all of [google's camera specific intents (MediaStore)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Camera) open up a simplifed version of the camera app. I don't need the user to take a photo, I need them to open the "real" camera app.

My second option is via an intent chooser/dialog. [See this example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#disambiguation-dialog): By adding a map url android will show I dialog of all apps that can take a map uri. But I have not found a way to do this type of functionality with apps that take images.

[Unsolved question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734367/how-to-open-camera-with-default-camera-function-in-android-app)

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: "The intention is that the user will be directed to open a camera app that allows for the scanning of QR codes" -- there are hundreds of camera apps. None have to allow for scanning QR codes. For example, I use Open Camera, and it (at least at present) does not have a QR code scanning option. If you want to scan QR codes, [integrate a QR code scanner](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/81?sort=created).

Comment: I understand. I am okay with the intent not working on all devices. There is no guarantee that any camera app can scan QR codes, or that the default camera app has this functionality. What I want to do is make it easier for a user who knows that they have a camera app that can scan QR codes to access the camera quickly without implementing it as part of the app if possible.

Comment: You can try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA